# Separate colors in a Unity Image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to color a greyscaled sprite on an Image object in my unity project. It all works when i assign just one color, like:

```
image.color = new Color(..)
```

But now i'm looking for a way to fill that as a vertical flag with color given from input in a function, with the image aswell. This procedure only color the image with the last color passed and doesn't equally split painting...

```
public static void ColorizeImageAsFlag(Image image, List<Color> colors)
    {
        if (colors.Count < 2)
        {
            if (colors.Count == 1)
                image.color = colors[0];
            else
                image.color = Color.white;
            return;
        }

        float height = image.minHeight;
        float width = image.minWidth;

        float colorWidth = width / (colors.Count - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Count; i++)
        {
            float yPos = height * i / colors.Count;

            image.color = colors[i];
            image.fillAmount = colorWidth;
            image.fillOrigin = (int)Image.OriginVertical.Top;

            image.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, yPos);
        }
    }
```

I'm asking for some help and it would be awesome if someone is also able to color it with a slightly diagonal division, but always with a vertical allignment between the segment with just a coefficent i guess...

Comment: [`color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-color.html) is just an overall color tint for the image .. your assignment in the loop is useless as it will just keep the last one ... You probably rather wanted to go through the according [sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-sprite.html) and then the according [texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Sprite-texture.html) and finally the [pixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-color.html) is just an overall color tint for the image .. your assignments in the loop are useless as it will just keep the last iteration.

You probably rather wanted to go through the according [`sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-sprite.html) and then the according [`texture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Sprite-texture.html) and finally the [pixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html)

I think something like this should do it

```
    public static void ColorizeImageAsFlag(Image image, List<Color> colors)
    {
        var sprite = image.sprite;
        var textureRect = sprite.textureRect;
        var texture = sprite.texture;

        var height = Mathf.RoundToInt(textureRect.height);
        var width = Mathf.RoundToInt(textureRect.width);
        var colorWidth = width / (float)colors.Count;

        var start = Vector2Int.RoundToInt(textureRect.min);

        var pixels = texture.GetPixels(start.x, start.y, width, height);

        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                var color = colors.Count switch
                {
                    0 => Color.white,
                    1 => colors[0],
                    _ => colors[Mathf.FloorToInt(x / colorWidth)]
                };

                pixels[y * width + x] = color;
            }
        }

        texture.SetPixels(start.x, start.y, width, height, pixels);
        texture.Apply();
    }
```

And then

- you have to make sure of course your image has an according sprite assigned
- The texture asset needs to have Read/Write enabled
- and if this is supposed to be used by different instances each of them needs their own respective sprite and texture instances!

  => might be even easier to rather let your method create a fresh texture and sprite every time